# Error in fetching table through JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch data from a table in MySQL using JpaRepository.
I am geeting an error by running code like -

Error creating bean with name 'chassiscontroller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service': Error creating bean with name 'chassisserviceimpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao': Error creating bean with name 'chassisdao' defined in com.ChassisInfo.chassis.dao.chassisdao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.ChassisInfo.model.chassismodel.

Controller

```
package com.ChassisInfo.chassis.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ChassisInfo.chassis.model.ChassisModel;
import com.ChassisInfo.chassis.service.ChassisService;

@RestController
public class ChassisController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ChassisService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/chnum")
    public List<ChassisModel> getchassisnumberinfo(){
        
        return service.getAll();
    
    }

}
```

Service-

```
package com.ChassisInfo.chassis.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.ChassisInfo.chassis.model.ChassisModel;

public interface ChassisService{

    

    List<ChassisModel> getAll();
    

}
```

ServiceImpl-

```
package com.ChassisInfo.chassis.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ChassisInfo.chassis.dao.ChassisDao;
import com.ChassisInfo.chassis.model.ChassisModel;



@Service
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
public class ChassisServiceimpl implements ChassisService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ChassisDao dao;

    @Override
    public List<ChassisModel> getAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dao.findAll();
    }
```

Dao-

```
package com.ChassisInfo.chassis.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ChassisInfo.chassis.model.ChassisModel;

@Repository
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface ChassisDao extends JpaRepository<ChassisModel,String> {
   
   @Query(value = "Select * from chassis_master" ,nativeQuery  = true)
    List<ChassisModel> findAll();
}
```

Model-

```
package com.ChassisInfo.model;

public class chassismodel {
    private String vin;
    private String active;
    private String chassisNumber;
    private String chassisSeries;
    private String statusChangedTime;
    private String tag;
    private String truckid;
    private String id;
    private String chassis_number;
    private String chassis_series;
    private String status_changed_time;
    private String truck_id;
    
    public String getVin() {
        return vin;
    }

    public void setVin(String vin) {
        this.vin = vin;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getChassisSeries() {
        return chassisSeries;
    }

    public void setChassisSeries(String chassisSeries) {
        this.chassisSeries = chassisSeries;
    }

    public String getStatusChangedTime() {
        return statusChangedTime;
    }

    public void setStatusChangedTime(String statusChangedTime) {
        this.statusChangedTime = statusChangedTime;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getTruckid() {
        return truckid;
    }

    public void setTruckid(String truckid) {
        this.truckid = truckid;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getChassis_number() {
        return chassis_number;
    }

    public void setChassis_number(String chassis_number) {
        this.chassis_number = chassis_number;
    }

    public String getChassis_series() {
        return chassis_series;
    }

    public void setChassis_series(String chassis_series) {
        this.chassis_series = chassis_series;
    }

    public String getStatus_changed_time() {
        return status_changed_time;
    }

    public void setStatus_changed_time(String status_changed_time) {
        this.status_changed_time = status_changed_time;
    }

    public String getTruck_id() {
        return truck_id;
    }

    public void setTruck_id(String truck_id) {
        this.truck_id = truck_id;
    }

    public String getChassisNumber() {
        return chassisNumber;
    }

    public void setChassisNumber(String chassisNumber) {
        this.chassisNumber = chassisNumber;
    }

}
```

ChassisApplication-

```
package com.ChassisInfo.chassis;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.ChassisInfo.chassis.controller.ChassisController;



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ChassisApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ChassisApplication.class, args);
        ChassisController chassisController = context.getBean(ChassisController.class);
        chassisController.getchassisnumberinfo();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your model isn't an entity so how should this work? YOu are using JPA, use the proper mappings.

Comment: "trying to fetch data from a table in MySQL" and "using JpaRepository" already seem to hint as a misconception. With JPA you should think in _entities_  which are expressed as Java classes and are mapped to tables. So when you fetch data you fetch entities and only in rare cases should the mapping to tables even matter (it's important of course but normally not for the fetching code). So stop thinking "tables" and start thinking "entities".

Comment: There are a couple of other issues in your code: 1) naming: you should read the Java code conventions and stick to them, e.g. class names start with a capital letter, almost everything else with a lower case letter. 2) You need to read up on Spring's "query methods", i.e. `findbychassisNumber()` would indicate a load by "chassisNumber" (albeit the name is somewhat wrong) which also requires a number to be passed as a parameter. 3) Use native queries like `Select * from chassis_master` when you _have_ to and let Spring do its thing when you don't (or don't know you have to).

Comment: Implememnted all changes still getting same error @Thomas

Comment: Well, my comments were related to _other_ issues with your code and not necessarily meant to solve the primary issue. Often, a better design solves obvious issues as well but it seems not in your case. It _seems_ as if the entity `chassismodel` is not being recognized as such - and the reason would be that there's no ` @Entity` annotation on that class.

Comment: Thanks resolved by using '@Entity' 
                                          '@Table' and '@Id' in ChassisModel

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` (lombok) in `chassisserviceimpl`, since dao field is not accessible for autowiring. Also add final for the field:

```
private final chassisdao dao;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are missing the @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.package.name") in you @SpringBootApplication

This is the Annotation to enable JPA repositories. Will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories by default.